# Converting Merge Sort pseudocode to running Java code

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

I tried to convert this Merge Sort pseudocode into Java but don't get the right output. Here is the pseudocode:

```
Merge-Sort(A, p, r )
   if p < r
     then q←(p+r)/2 
     Merge-Sort(A, p, q)
     Merge-Sort(A, q + 1, r )
     Merge(A, p, q, r )


Merge(A, p, q, r )
   for k←1 to r−p+1 do
     if j>r or (i ≤ q and A[i] ≤ A[j])
     then B[k]←A[i]; i←i+1 else B[k]←A[j];j←j+1
   for k←1 to r−p+1 do A[k+p−1]←B[k]
```

And this is my Java code for it:

public class MergeSort {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {2, 6, 3, 5, 1};
    mergeSort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + a[i]);
    }
}

public static void mergeSort(int[] a, int from, int to) {
    final int begin = from, end = to;
    if (begin < end) {
        final int mid = (begin + end) / 2;
        MergeSort.mergeSort(a, begin, mid);
        MergeSort.mergeSort(a,  mid+1, end);
        MergeSort.merge(a, begin, mid, end);
    }
}

private static void merge(int[] a, int from, int mid, int to) {
    final int begin = from, mitte = mid, end = to;

    int[] B = new int[a.length];

    int i = begin, j = mitte;
    for (int k = 0; k <= end-begin; k++) {
        if (j > end || (i <= mitte && a[i] <= a[j])) {
            B[k] = a[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            B[k] = a[j];
            j++;
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < end-begin; k++) {
        a[k + begin] = B[k];
    }
}
```

Sadly it is not working like that. I think i do something wrong with some indexes but I can't figure out where exactly the error is.
I need to stick as close as possible to this pseudocode.
It would be great if someone could show me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The debugger is your greatest friend in situations like this.

Comment: @Peter Winzer Hope it helps, feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pseudocode given for the Merge algorithm is somewhat incorrect because it does not say anything about the situation when **only one pointer moves while other remains stationary**.

In the above mentioned case you would have to separately fill out temporary array for by moving that stationary pointer.

Also the required length of B is `to - from + 1` and it should be `j = mitte + 1` instead of `j = mitte` The correct code for the merge is :

```
private static void merge(int[] a, int from, int mid, int to) {
        final int begin = from, mitte = mid, end = to;

        int[] B = new int[end-begin+1];
        int k=0;
        int i = begin, j = mitte+1;
        while(i<=mid&&j<=end)
            if(a[i]<=a[j]){
                B[k++] = a[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                B[k++] = a[j];
                j++;
            }
        //in case i remained stationary
        while(i<=mid)
            B[k++] = a[i++];

        //in case j remained stationary
        while(j<=end)
            B[k++] = a[j++];

        //Now copy the array
        i=0;
        for(k=begin;k<=end;++k)
         a[k]=B[i++];
    }
```